# Can't get devices language in phonegap

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, globalization, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm doing [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#Globalization) exact example from the phonegap docs.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>getPreferredLanguage Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function checkLanguage() {
  navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
    function (language) {alert('language: ' + language.value + '\n');},
    function () {alert('Error getting language\n');}
  );
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <button onclick="checkLanguage()">Click for language</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When I click the button I want it to return the language I'm using on my phone.
It works good if I run it through the PhoneGap app, while connected to the local server on my computer (phonegap serve) however it won't work after making the  .apk and installing it on my phone. What am I missing?

edit: here's the config.xml
http://pastebin.com/t6fx3jRD

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
 xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>hi bi</name>
<description>
    sample stuff
</description>
<author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
    PhoneGap Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0" />
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<icon src="icon.png" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Please add `config.xml` to your post.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any obvious problems, but there are five things that should be resolved.

1. you need to post your config.xml to this forum. If you delete that pastebin file, others will not be able to benefit from this. (If we can get it to work.)
2. you are using the generic file, which is not a bad thing, except the large file makes it more difficult to spot a problem.
3. you did NOT use `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="X.X.X" />`, which is not required.  But since you do not, then by default you get the latest version (the bleeding edge) of the phonegap. (This might get you leading edge bugs which would be difficult to debug -- without asking for lots of help.)
4. Since you are using the latest version of Phonegap, and not 3.3.0, then you should reference [leading edge](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.globalization) - which does not have an full example.
5. Since you did NOT say what your target platform is, then perhaps you should look at the [Bug List](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB/component/12320649/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:component-summary-panel)

Lastly, you might consider using an earlier version, say  `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0" />`, and try you build again. Oh and RTFM.

Best of Luck, Jesse

Comment: Hi and thanks. 1. Done. 2. Done. 3,4,5 Done. I added the <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0" /> in the config.xml, but however I have installed on my computer the latest version of phonegap, should i downgrade the instalation as well? BTW, now it shows the language. Also, I did read and still am the FM.

Comment: No need to downgrade. Phonegap/Cordova is pretty good at fixing bugs, so when you upgrade you get bug fixes, even on old version - if it is not deprecated. FWIW: the FM can be unclear, and have errors. Here is [one I found at Apple](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-07-02.jssnippets.html) recently.